# When using a {domain} wildcard, is there a way to globally set the route( ['domain' => $domain] ) property (not at a function level)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Laravel 5.5

Using a group in RouteServiceProvider for {domain}

I want to be able to call Named Routes in blade without having to pass

`public function pageName($domain){ 
    return view('mypage', ['domain'=>$domain,'othervars'=>$domain)]) 
}`

and avoid this mess in blade:

`{{ route('nameOfRoute', ['domain'=>$domain]) }}`

Instead i would love to simply in my route group set the `route(['domain'])` property to be $domain and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

No global way to set it, but instead, wrap the `route('name')` default helper function with my own helper function, and add the param to the array.

Example function:

```
function orgRoute($route, $params = [])
{
    if (!is_array($params)){
        $params = [$params];
    }

    // Set the domain value if not set, null, or jibberish
    if (!isset($params['domain']) || $params['domain']=='{domain}' || $params['domain'] == '')
    {
        // Instance of App Domain is set in OrgBaseController __construct()
        $domain = \App::make('current_domain');
        $params['domain'] = $domain;
    }


    return route($route, $params);
}
```